# PHPUnit/DBUnit - createDefaultDBConnection() not accepting schema name

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpunit

I am working on using PHPUnit/DBUnit to test the interaction with a database. Thus far, I have been unable to get past `creatDefaultDBConnection()`. The database has already been created in MySQL, and I fairly confident the initial PDO connection is succeeding since I have not received any error messages to convince me otherwise. `createDefaultDBConnection()` takes the PDO handler and the schema name. I have provided both, yet I consistently get this error:

> Argument 1 passed to PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DefaultTester::__construct() must
>       implement interface PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DB_IDatabaseConnection, null given,
>       called in ..///PHPUnit/Extensions/Database/TestCase.php on line 132 and
>       defined

Here is the test:

```
require_once('../includes/file/to/include.php');

class Core extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase 
{
    static private $pdo = null; 

    public function getConnection() 
    {
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname", 'root', "root");
        $this->createDefaultDBConnection($pdo, "dbname");
    }

    ...
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was fixed by returning `$this->createDefaultDBConnection($pdo, "dbname")`.

thus,

```
public function getConnection()
{
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname", 'root', "root");
    return $this->createDefaultDBConnection($pdo, "dbname");
}
```

Noob mistake

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion ...

You might want to consider making your connection a static variable so that it can be re-used. :)

```
static private $pdo;
static private $conn;

final public function getConnection()
{
    if (is_null(static::$conn))
    {
        if (is_null(static::$pdo))
        {
            static::$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', 'root', 'root');
        }

        static::$conn = $this->createDefaultDBConnection(static::$pdo, 'dbname');
    }

    return static::$conn;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet as my lack of reputation. Here is the good suggestion of @bashaus, juts fixing the way static properties should be called. :)

```
static private $pdo;
static private $conn;

final public function getConnection()
{
    if ( is_null( self::$conn ) )
    {
        if ( is_null( self::$pdo ) )
        {
            self::$pdo = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', 'root', 'root' );
        }

        self::$conn = $this->createDefaultDBConnection( self::$pdo, 'dbname' );
    }

    return self::$conn;
}
```